# How do i display the output of NSURLSession using NSLog?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nslog

I want the display the output of a URl using NSLog.

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
NSURLSession *session;
NSString *londonWeatherUrl;
NSURLRequest *request;
}
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

londonWeatherUrl = @"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=2de143494c0b295cca9337e1e96b00e0";

request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                         [NSURL URLWithString:londonWeatherUrl]];


[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:londonWeatherUrl]
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                            NSURLResponse *response,
                            NSError *error) {}] resume];

session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSLog(@"%@",);  // what goes here ?
}
```

Can someone tell me what do i need to have inside NSLog so that the output of that URL is displayed in the log.
Sorry, i am a beginner in objective C.

Comment: "output of a Url" - do you mean "Response"?

Comment: @Sandr - yes, the response

Comment: The `NSLog` goes to that completion handler (between `{` and `}`). Your `data` is a parameter of the completion handler. You can display that data in hexadecimal format or you will have to parse it first (JSON, UIImage etc).

Answer (score 1):

You can handle response calling:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

londonWeatherUrl = @"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=2de143494c0b295cca9337e1e96b00e0";

request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                     [NSURL URLWithString:londonWeatherUrl]];


[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:londonWeatherUrl]
    completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                          NSURLResponse *response,
                          NSError *error) {
        // handle response
        NSLog(@"%@", response);

 }] resume];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your response code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

londonWeatherUrl = @"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=2de143494c0b295cca9337e1e96b00e0";

request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                         [NSURL URLWithString:londonWeatherUrl]];


    [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:londonWeatherUrl]
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                NSURLResponse *response,
                                NSError *error) {

        NSError* error;
        NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error]; //Provide your NSData here to convert to dictionary

        //NSArray *responses = [json objectForKey:@"YOUR KEY"]; //Provide your key if contain array or else directly use as dictionary

        NSLog(@"Data dictionary: %@", jsonDictionary);
        NSLog(@"NSURLResponse: %@", response);

}] resume];

session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];    

}
```

Comment: How do you access response outside of completionHandler block?